# Create a class with vectorized properties

Tags: python, class, vectorization

Vectorized functions are way faster than doing it on your own, e.g.
`np.exp(a)` is faster than `[math.exp(i) for i in a]`.

I'm creating my own class with several attributes. At some point I want to be able to delete/add new attributes to the several objects. can this be done in a (fast) vectorized way?
i.e.

```
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self)
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
```

After having initialized some instances of this class and saved them in a list, i.e. `instances = [ClassName() for i in range(100)]`.

I now want the code

```
for instance in instances:
    del instance.a
```

in the following form: `del instances.a`. I know how I could do this by creating a meta class instances which has this attribute/this method. But this would just mask the for loop. Is there a way in which it is actually done in a vetorized, fast way?

In general, how can I tell my classes to have instances, that allow vectorized functions?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what vectorized operations are.  Vectorization in the sense you describe is specific to numpy.  It only has meaningful performance benefits for numeric computations, because it is tied to strict memory layouts for numpy's numeric types, which are manipulated in C.  You can't "vectorize" arbitrary Python operations without using numpy (or some other library written in C).

Comment: Yes, I was afraid this would be the answer :(